# what to do with a constant of a scalar potential if all you need is a constant

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-fields

if i construct a simple scalar potential say 
$F=[0,1,2z]$
then
fx=0
fy=0
fz=2
so $ f = 2z + g (x,y) $
now what? what function of x and y could equal 1?

Comment: Seems like you’re going in the wrong direction. $F$ is a vector field, not a scalar potential.

Answer (score 0):

Let's role with **F** = $0$**i** + **j** + $2z$**k**

Potential functions require that

**F** $=\nabla{f}$

Then

$\frac{\partial{f}}{dx}=0$

$\frac{\partial{f}}{dy}=1$

$\frac{\partial{f}}{dz}=2z$

We can start anywhere we would like. Let's start with the first

$f(x,y,z) = C_1(y,z)$

$f$ is indepedent of $x$. Now take the y partial

$\frac{\partial{f}}{dy}=\frac{\partial{C_1}}{dy} = 1$

Solve for $C_1$

$C_1(y,z) = y + C_2(z)$

$f(y,z) = y + C_2(z)$

$\frac{\partial{f}}{dz}=\frac{\partial{C_2}}{dz} = 2z$

$C_2(z) = z^2 + K$

So

$f(x,y,z) = y + z^2 + K$

For some constant K

Comment: im really sorry, thats pretty cool, but i got it slightly wrong at frist df/dz = 2 not 2z and also wouldnt df/dy = 0 for yours and not 1?

Comment: You don't actually take the gradient of F. We can only work with what we're given, which is that F = grad(f). All we know is that each partial of f is equal to its respective component in F and we work from there.